# arabic text to bitmap conversion

Tags: android, bitmap, arabic

I tried the following method to convert my Arabic text to bitmap in Android. But the function always returns null. Can anybody tell me what is happening?

**my String="نقد"**

```
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte1 = encodedString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(encodeByte1, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: must be the funniest question ever asked on StackOverflow

Comment: @OfekRon who are you to judge????

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like this. `decode` means it will decompress the bytes (usually from JPG or PNG formats).

If you want text to bitmap you have to draw on the bitmap yourself. Something similar to this.

```
String text = "your text";
// create a text paint
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
// configure text paint
... see on the link below how to configure TextPaint
// based on the configuration, get size in pixels
int width = (int)tp.measureText(text);
int height = text height ?
// create bitmap with proper size
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
// create canvas to execute drawing
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// draw on the bitmap
canvas.drawText(text, 0, height/2, tp);
```

**TextPaint:** 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using funny way to do it(which obviously won't work), anyway, you may use canvas drawText for your purposes or also you may create TextView, set this text, and then get drawing cache.